# SCSS / Sass - Statement referencing to parent not work

Tags: if-statement, sass, compass-sass

```
.a, .b
{
   color: red;

   $x: &;

   @if $x == '.b'
   {
     color: $x;
   }


}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/ad7fa7f3a431f3e2d4e0

Not work, why? Could you help me someone with some fix?

Answer (score 0):

Because `$x` is equal to the full selector (`.a, .b`), never to `.a` or `.b`.

What you're trying to achieve would be:

```
.a, .b {
  color: red;

  &.b {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

But it will generate this code (working, but not optimized):

```
.a, .b {
  color: red;
}
.a.b, .b.b {
  color: blue;
}
```