# Xpath - PHP - sum values (not working)

Tags: html, xpath, numbers, sum

Im trying from this page http://fotbal.zylacup.cz/disciplinarni-rizeni-list.php from 6 cell get value (only number) and sum it.

When I use  SUM() -> i get NaN, when I use number with sum i get invalid Xpath .... can u help me how sum it?

```
//*[@id='c2']/table//tr/td[6]//text() // get value 

 sum(number(*[@id='c2']/table//tr/td[6]//text())) // invalid Path

 sum(*[@id='c2']/table//tr/td[6]//text()) // NaN!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `//*[@id='c2']/table//tr/td[6]//text()` to the input document, you *don't* get numbers, this is what those cells contain (showing only part of the cells):

```
50 Kč
-----------------------
50 Kč
-----------------------
100 Kč
-----------------------
50 Kč
-----------------------
80 Kč
-----------------------
50 Kč
-----------------------
50 Kč
-----------------------
30 Kč
-----------------------
130 Kč
```

I have no idea what "Kč" is, but it should be trivial to realize that a string like "30 Kč" cannot be automatically converted to a number.

If you are using XPath 2.0, you could use an expression like

```
sum(
    for $x in //*[@id='c2']/table//tr/td[6]//text()
    return number(substring-before(normalize-space($x),' K'))
   )
```

and the result would be the sum as a single number.

With XPath 1.0 you *cannot* sum those cells with a single XPath expression. Then, you'd have to reach for the higher-level language you use XPath in,

- find all relevant cell values with an XPath expression
- then use the string functions of that language to take the substring before "Kč"
- convert the rest to numbers and sum them

Comment: Thx for fast and fantastic answer. Im using XPath 1.0. Can you show me how replace "Kč" - its only currency, dont need this.

Comment: @user1385156 As I said, then, you have to use the environment you use Xpath in. In your case, it seems to be PHP. So, if you are asking how to write this PHP code, you should _tag_ the question with `php`. By the way, you should really accept [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26524547/1987598) to a previous question of yours.